# NoSQL support in .NET

Tags: .net, nosql

NoSQL is unquestionably a popular technology in modern enterprise.

Are there any out of the box support for NoSQL provided in the .NET ecosystem?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options in the NoSQL environment for Windows. Perhaps you can be a bit more specific about your requirements or technical challenges?

A starter list of databases might include RavenDB, Redis, MongoDB, CouchDB, Postgres, MySql, Cassandra, HBase, ElasticSearch, Solr - all of which have .Net clients or there are .Net libs that can provide interop.  I personally have used Cassandra, HBase, ElasticSearch and Solr with great success.  Lastly, you can also use SQL in Azure or just turn SQL Server into a KeyValue store(if your data is xml, sql server can even provide indexing into the document).

Answer (score 0):

**[NosDB](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/)**

> **Open Source NoSQL Database for .NET**
>
> NosDB is a 100% native .NET Open Source NoSQL Database (released under the Apache 2.0 License). NosDB is extremely fast and linearly scalable and allows your .NET applications to handle extreme transaction loads (XTP).
>
> NosDB also helps you accelerate your .NET development by providing a flexible JSON schema. With JSON, you can quickly adjust to your changing requirements and lower your time to market and your cost of ownership.